# No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

Tags: database, netbeans, driver

I'm following this tutorial : https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html

All is working until this :

[image]

The two resources don't display in each category.
I have still continued the tutorial and i get this error :

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource
>   invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

I have added the Connector in the libraries...
Can someone help ?

Comment: The right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571575/unable-to-create-connection-to-glassfish-database-with-netbeans

Answer (score 3):

We had this tutorial assigned as a class exercise and we all ran into the same problem. Something with updates puts the "glassfish-resources.xml" in the WEB-INF section of your project. Left-click and drag this file into your "Server Resources" folder then right-click on your project folder. You should now see the jdbc/IFWAFCAD in the JDBC Resources and IfpwafcadPool in the JDBC Connection Pools of your GlassFish Server Resources.

Answer (score 0):

I also had followed this document and got a similar error. Because of, I was wrong with "Referencing the data source from the application"."For Resource Name, enter the resource name that you gave when configuring the data source for the server".
I could run successfully after correct it.

[image: JDBC data source and connection pool]
[image: Edit Resource reference to reference the data source]